# Find users widget

Tags: php, mysql

I am NOT experienced with php/mysql at all, this is what I have so far.

I want to make a section on my webpage that shows 5 random users, so I have made 5 querys output 1 user each, its working fine, but I have some things I need help adding, I want the username I am currently logged in as excluded, and I want there to be no repeat usernames. My code I have so far is below, help is extremely appreciated.

```
include "connect.php";
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5");
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        $random = $row['username'];

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5");
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        $random2 = $row['username'];

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5");
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        $random3 = $row['username'];

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5");
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        $random4 = $row['username'];

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5");
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        $random5 = $row['username'];

        echo "
        <div class='well well-sm' style='padding-top:4px;padding-bottom:8px; margin-bottom:8px; overflow:hidden; background:white;'>
            <a href='./$random'>$random</a><br>
            <a href='./$random2'>$random2</a><br>
            <a href='./$random3'>$random3</a><br>
            <a href='./$random4'>$random4</a><br>
            <a href='./$random5'>$random5</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do a google on using loops and mysqli, you'd be able to fetch all 5 users in one query instead of 5 queries. Also, I'd strongly suggest stop using mysql and use PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what would be the advantages of using PDO or mysqli compared to standard mysql?

Comment: This is an atrocious sin but `$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where username <> '".$_SESSION['username']."' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5");`

Comment: Mysql is deprecated, meaning that it's not in use anymore. (Except in older versions of php), also, security.

Comment: You can find an excellent tutorial on PDO here: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username <> "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $username) . '" ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $random[] = $row['username'];           
}

foreach ($random as $random_user) { //echo name of each random user
        echo $random_user . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: This is still showing my username and duplicating 1 username 5 times :(

Answer (score 0):

If your username is stored in $username you can do

```
$list= array();
$list[]=$username;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username NOT IN $list ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5");
```

Then you can simply add the usernames from each iteration to the list.

I'd also think a loop would be more effective.

I'm a little confused though, Limit 5 indicates you expect 5 results from your query but you pull one from the assoc array.

If your query returns 5 rows(which you can check by running it in phpMyAdmin or whatever SQL control panel you have), then you don't need to keep running it and it shouldn't return duplicates anyway.  You just run :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$list[]=$row;
}
```

Then you can use the list to limit further iterations AND to store all of the users you've acquired.

Also, you should note that the mysql extension is deprecated, you want mySQLi or PDO_MySQL for security.